# SQL Select entries with its associated images

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I don't work with SQL all that much so I'm kinda lost on this one.

I have three tables:

images (id, image_path)

shop_entries (id, title, ....)

shop_img (shop_id, img_id)

I want to display all shop entries and its associated images. Currently my SQL is returning shop_entries mutliple times (each time with 1 image associated with it). I want to return the shop_entries only once but with multiple images linked to it.

My SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT s.*, images.*  
FROM shop_entries s 
LEFT JOIN shop_img ON shop_img.shop_id = s.id 
LEFT JOIN images ON images.id = shop_img.img_id
```

Update*
The answer below worked, but now I wanted to add another table to the query, same principle: besides the images I have a table "sizes" and "shop_sizes".

This query resulted in double images and double sizes, what's wrong here:

```
Select SE.*

 , Group_Concat(I.path Order By I.path ASC Separator ', ') as images
 , Group_Concat(S.title Order By S.title ASC Separator ', ') as sizes
 From shop_entries As SE

            Left Join shop_img As SI
                On SI.shop_id = SE.id
            Left Join images As I
                On I.id = SI.img_id

            Left Join shop_sizes As SS
                On SS.shop_id = SE.id
            Left Join sizes As S
                On S.id = SS.size_id

        Group By SE.id, SE.title
```

Comment: How should the images appear: A comma-delimited list of paths?

Comment: Please show us expected result in case when one entry has several images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group images and sizes separately, then join the result sets to `shop_entries` to obtain the final output:

```
SELECT
  SE.*,
  COALESCE(GI.images, '') AS images,
  COALESCE(GS.sizes,  '') AS sizes
FROM shop_entries AS SE

  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      SI.shop_id,
      GROUP_CONCAT(I.path ORDER BY I.path ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS images
    FROM shop_img AS SI
      INNER JOIN images AS I ON SI.img_id = I.id
    GROUP BY SI.shop_id
  ) AS GI ON SE.id = GI.shop_id

  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      SS.shop_id,
      GROUP_CONCAT(S.title ORDER BY S.title ASC SEPARATOR ', ') AS sizes
    FROM shop_sizes AS SS
      INNER JOIN sizes AS S ON SS.size_id = S.id
    GROUP BY SS.shop_id
  ) AS GS ON SE.id = GS.shop_id
```

Comment: It should be noted that this solution presents the possibility that the path list will not match with the title list. E.g., imagine the following paths: ("A:\Foo.jpg",15 KB)("A:\Zulu.jpg", 10 KB). However, if you give both Group_Concat calls the same Order By, that should give paired results...unless path and/or size can be null.

Comment: @Thomas: I guess your note must indicate our different reading of the question. I have no idea what the sizes are about, but you seem to think they are associated with images. I would expect the association to be implemented in the form of a column in either `images` or `sizes`, but the design isn't mine. So, you may be quite right in your estimation.

Answer (score 3):

```
Select SE.ie, SE.title
    , Group_Concat(I.image_path Order By I.image_path ASC Separator ', ')
From shop_entries As SE
    Left Join shop_img As SI
        On SI.shop_id = SE.id
    Left Join images As I
        On I.id = SI.img_id
Group By SE.ie, SE.title
```

Comment: @a1ex07 - Technically, yes I need only group on `ID`, but IMO it is better for clarity if you are explicit with the columns on which you are grouping.

Comment: This worked! I added "as images" behind the group_concat to format it better in the result. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I updated my question, I need to add another table (sizes): same principle as the images. Thought this would be easy with your SQL but I'm doing something wrong.